# Can't load layers into ArcGIS Viewer for Silverlight

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, silverlight, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

I am trying to load layers into ArcGIS Viewer for Silverlight. I have uploaded my files into the server successfully. However when I browse for the files I get connection error. I know the files are uploaded into the server because I can see them when I use the same file path to the server for Flex Viewer.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you published a map service containing those layers?